# Mail server and custom incoming logger/filter/agent

Tags: postfix, email-server, exim, agent

I have to write an application and link it to a new postfix or exim4 mail server, this application must fully read and process all incoming messages. As *optional* requirement it may filter some messages according to mail content.
After that I need a very common mail-server.

What is the best approach for that? Is is possibile to attach an agent/filter to a MTA like postfix or exim4?

---

Just for clarification, this will be used for automated mail-exchange between systems and this application should read all incoming email to store some state vars in a database. However, the mail exchange will be done by standard pop3/smtp protocol, so I prefer to use a standard mailserver. I can consider both Exim or Postfix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword that you look for is **milter** (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milter)). This is a standardized interface to program plugins into most open-source SMTP servers.

(Also, please note that furhter programming questions re. said milter are better directed to stackoverflow.com sister site.)

Comment: You were too fast... I have to wait 2 mins :-D

Comment: Where can I find some informations how to develope a new exim4 milter? Seems that "milter" is not supported by exim4 but only from sendmail or postfix.